# How to prove that strictly decreasing monotone series

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that a  strictly decreasing monotone series with positive values for all $a_n$ converges to 0?

Comment: As stated, that is not true.  Consider $a_n=1+\frac 1n$.

Comment: true thank you lulu

Comment: So how do you want to fix your question?

Comment: You also need the assumption that $\inf a_n = 0$.